# Unable to locate package on 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, vlc

I am not able to install any software through terminal. When I run following commands,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

I get an error message saying `unable to locate package`.

Comment: There's no Ubuntu 14.0 , can you show the actual output you get when installing thru terminal? There's also No need to add a third party repository, VLC is in the Official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In the PPA you list, there are no `vlc-plugin-` packages at all, so of course it is not found, all you need to do is

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

To make sure you install any plugins that are there too use

```
sudo apt-get install vlc*
```

This will get all packages that start with `vlc`.